# SubEthaSMTP server: MimeMessage throws Exception

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have implemented SubEthaSMTP server, I can read messages successfully. How can I use it like every other mail servers like GMail or Yahoo. Example like, list root folders, mark message as read? Create folders like inbox, send, read and trash if not exist? Copy message to sent or trash folder? Forward or reply messages. With IMAP I can do all of it, even listening to each of the folder for a new message. Exception is thrown whenever I cast MimeMessage to IMAPFolder to get the folder name or get mimemessage MessageID

This is my SMTPServerConfig class

```
 @Configuration
 public class SMTPServerConfig {

    private final SMTPServer smtpServer;
    private final SimpleMessageListener marketingMsgListener;
    private final UsernamePasswordValidator authValidator;
    private final EasyAuthenticationHandlerFactory easyAuth;

    public SMTPServerConfig(SimpleMessageListener marketingMsgListener) {
       authValidator = new SimpleAuthValidatorImpl();
       easyAuth = new EasyAuthenticationHandlerFactory(authValidator);
       this.marketingMsgListener = marketingMsgListener;

       this.smtpServer = SMTPServer
            .port(25001)
            .simpleMessageListener(this.marketingMsgListener)
            .requireAuth(true)
            .authenticationHandlerFactory(easyAuth)
            .hostName("localhost")
            .hideTLS(false)
            .enableTLS(true)
            .requireTLS(false)
            .requireAuth(true)
            .connectionTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .maxMessageSize(10000)
            .maxConnections(20)
            .build();

       this.smtpServer.stop();
       this.smtpServer.start();
   }
```

This is the mail listener

```
 @Configuration
 public class MailListener implements SimpleMessageListener {

   private static final String MARKETING_DOMAIN = "@marketingchris.com";
   private final EmailContentService emailContentService;


   public MailListener(EmailContentService emailContentService) {
     this.emailContentService = emailContentService;
   }

   /**
    * Check if the received email is for this listener based on business logic (recipient email address)
   *
   * @param from is a the sender email address.
   * @param recipient is a the recipient email address.
   *
   * @return true if the recipient is an address of MARKETING department.
   */
   @Override
   public boolean accept(String from, String recipient) {
      System.out.println("Recipient : "+recipient);
      return recipient != null && recipient.endsWith(MARKETING_DOMAIN);
   }

   @Override
   public void deliver(String from, String recipient, InputStream data) {
      System.out.println("From : "+from);
      System.out.println("Recipient : "+recipient);
      try {
        emailContentService.extractReceivedEmail(data);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
 }
```

I converted InputStream to MimeMessage

```
 @Service
 public class EmailContentServiceImpl implements EmailContentService {

    @Override
    public MimeMessage convertToMimeMessage(InputStream data) throws MessagingException {
       Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
       try {
           return new MimeMessage(session, data);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
           throw new MessagingException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ReceivedEmail extractReceivedEmail(InputStream data) throws Exception {
       ReceivedEmail receivedEmail = new ReceivedEmail();
       MimeMessage message;
       try {
           message = this.convertToMimeMessage(data);
           receivedEmail.setSubject(message.getSubject());
           receivedEmail.setSenderAddress(InternetAddress.toString(message.getFrom()));
           System.out.println(message.getMessageID()); // This throws an exception
           IMAPFolder folder = (IMAPFolder) message.getFolder();
           folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
           System.out.println("fullname " + folder.getFullName()); // This throws an exception
           return receivedEmail;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new Exception();
       }
    }
 }
```

This is the output

```
 DEBUG: setDebug: Jakarta Mail version 1.6.7
 DEBUG: getProvider() returning 
 javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
 DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
 DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=localhost, user=MY PC, password=<null>
 DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
 DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "localhost", port 25001, isSSL false
 220 localhost ESMTP SubEthaSMTP null
 DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "localhost", port: 25001
 EHLO DESKTOP-FFJA5IP
 250-localhost
 250-8BITMIME
 250-SIZE 10000
 250-STARTTLS
 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
 250 Ok
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10000"
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "Ok", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=localhost, user=christclau, password=<non-null>
 DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2
 DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
 DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
 yes Authenticated successfully
 DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
 DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
 MAIL FROM:<christoozu@gmail.com>
 250 Ok
 RCPT TO:<info@marketingchris.com>
 Recipient : info@marketingchris.com
 250 Ok
 DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
 DEBUG SMTP:   info@marketingchris.com
 DATA
 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
 Date: Sun, 27 Feb 2022 09:59:22 +0100 (WAT)
   From: christoozu@gmail.com
 To: info@marketingchris.com
 Message-ID: <472353602.8.1645952362453@DESKTOP-FFJA5IP>
 Subject: Password reset request
 MIME-Version: 1.0
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

 HI you have done sending mail with outlook
 From : christoozu@gmail.com
 Recipient : info@marketingchris.com
 ReceivedEmail{subject='Password reset request', senderAddress='christoozu@gmail.com', 
 senderName='null', recipientAddress='info@marketingchris.com', recipientName='null', cc='[]', 
  bcc='[]', contentType='text/plain; charset=us-ascii', attachments=[]}
  <472353602.8.1645952362453@DESKTOP-FFJA5IP>
 250 Ok
 DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server
 QUIT
 java.lang.Exception
 at org.cpa.churchms.subethasmtp.EmailContentServiceImpl.extractReceivedEmail(EmailContentServiceImpl.java:63)
at org.cpa.churchms.subethasmtp.MarketingMailListener.deliver(MarketingMailListener.java:39)
at org.subethamail.smtp.helper.SimpleMessageListenerAdapter$Handler.data(SimpleMessageListenerAdapter.java:137)
at org.subethamail.smtp.internal.command.DataCommand.execute(DataCommand.java:56)
at org.subethamail.smtp.internal.server.RequireTLSCommandWrapper.execute(RequireTLSCommandWrapper.java:32)
at org.subethamail.smtp.internal.server.RequireAuthCommandWrapper.execute(RequireAuthCommandWrapper.java:35)
at org.subethamail.smtp.internal.server.CommandHandler.handleCommand(CommandHandler.java:86)
at org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session.runCommandLoop(Session.java:220)
at org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session.run(Session.java:143)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
 221 Bye
 Done
```

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions and replace them with `Exception` without any information. Either just let the actual exception bubble up, use a more informative exception, and include the original exception as the `cause` parameter so we have more information. Please update your question to include the original exception stacktrace.

Comment: In the code shown, the message has no folder, because you just *received* the email, and transformed it from an `InputStream`, which just has the message headers and content, into a `MimeMessage`. It has not yet been associated with a folder If you want folder access, you need to work with the `Store` that contains a saved message. As an aside, as far as I'm aware SubEtha SMTP is not an IMAP server, it is a basic SMTP server, so it does not provide such features. Maybe instead you need to look at GreenMail server or Apache James.

Comment: Is SubEthaSMTP still a good library? Are there any other newer/better alternatives? Thanks